# How to display value from not selected combobox c#

Tags: c#

I need to display an unselected ComboBox value.

I have 10 ComboBoxes with `tag` values `1` through `10`.

When I select a ComboBox with a `tag` value of `1`, I have to check what is displayed from the ComboBox that has a `tag` value of `2`.

Selecting a ComboBox with a `tag` value of `5` should give me the value of the ComboBox that has a `tag` value of `6`.

```
public partial class workPlacePlan : Form
    {

        public workPlacePlan()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void workPlacePlan_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MaximumSize = this.Size;
            this.MinimumSize = this.Size;

            int cboId;
            int i = 1;

            string cboName; int c = 1;
            var items = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            ComboBox[] cbo = {
                cbo_1, cbo_2
            };

            foreach(ComboBox cbos in cbo)
            {
                items.Add(0, "-------");
                i = 1;
                while (i <= 24)
                {
                    cboId = i;
                    cboName = TimeSpan.FromHours(i).ToString("hh':'mm");

                    items.Add(cboId, cboName);
                    i++;
                }
                cbos.Tag = c;
                cbos.DataSource = new BindingSource(items, null);
                cbos.DisplayMember = "Value";
                cbos.ValueMember = "Key";
                items.Clear();

                cbos.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cboSelected);

                c++;

            }

        }

        public void cboSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cb = ((ComboBox)sender);
            int i_tmp;
            int tg = Int32.Parse(cb.Tag.ToString());

            if(tg % 2 == 0) //if is even
            {
                i_tmp= tg - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                i_tmp = tg + 1;
            }

        }

        private void cmd_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like code is missing.  What's with cb_tmp?  That's not useful.

Comment: I tried to set tag 
         ComboBox cb_tmp = new ComboBox();
        cb_tmp.Tag = i_tmp.ToString();

Comment: I see that.  What does that accomplish?

Comment: unfortunately nothing :(
I tried display not selected value combobox with tag = (tg - 1) but i dont know how to do....

Comment: Well, if you want help here, you should probably reduce your issue to just a couple ComboBoxes, and an explanation of what is happening vs what should happen.  I can't make heads or tails out of what you are trying to do with these tags, and how all the ComboBoxes relate to each other.

Comment: ok, so....i have two comboboxes cbo_1 with tag = 1 and cbo_2 with tag = 2 then when i selected cbo_1 i have to check what is selected on cbo_2. To do it I do not want to use his name but his tag.

i gave them event Handler

cbos.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cboSelected);

Comment: If you are looking for the matching ComboBox (I'm guessing), you would have to loop over the control's collection to find the matching ComboBox.  If the ComboBoxes are on the main form: `foreach (ComboBox cb in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()) {...}`  Then examine the matching tag value.

Comment: there are not in main form :/ I've just started learning c # so pls understand me.

Comment: Then replace "this" with the name of the panel or container the ComboBoxes are in.  This is why it's important to document your question properly.

Comment: yes, you're right. I edited my first post. Now is full code of window form

Comment: Well, use my foreach code I posted, change "this" with the name of the container they are in, and then check if the Tag of the control matches your i_tmp.

Comment: itąs not working

            foreach (ComboBox cbt in workPlacePlan.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()) {
                MessageBox.Show(cbt.Tag.ToString());
            }

Comment: This is where the debugger comes into play.  Put a debug stop on this line `ComboBox cb = ((ComboBox)sender);` and when the program hits it, walk through the code line by line (pressing F8).  Examine the variables when it's stopped to see what you get.

Comment: this is on red marked: workPlacePlan.Controls so i can't run debug

Comment: Does that mean you are getting a "'workPlacePlan' does not exist" error?  If so, your form doesn't have a panel with that name.

Comment: i didn't use panel in form ;/. Now i added the panel and it's working.
Could you  tell me how get value from second combobox ?
foreach (ComboBox cbt in panel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()) {
                if(Int32.Parse(cbt.Tag.ToString()) == Int32.Parse(i_tmp.ToString()))
                {
                    //display value from combobox wich tag name is i_tmp
                }   
            }

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
public partial class workPlacePlan : Form
    {

        public workPlacePlan()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void workPlacePlan_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MaximumSize = this.Size;
            this.MinimumSize = this.Size;

            int cboId;
            int i = 1;

            string cboName; int c = 1;
            var items = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            ComboBox[] cbo = {
                cbo_1_0, cbo_1_1, cbo_2_0, cbo_2_1, cbo_3_0, cbo_3_1, cbo_4_0, cbo_4_1, cbo_5_0, cbo_5_1, cbo_6_0, cbo_6_1,                
                cbo_13_0,cbo_13_1,cbo_14_0,cbo_14_1,cbo_15_0,cbo_15_1,cbo_16_0,cbo_16_1,cbo_17_0,cbo_17_1,cbo_18_0,cbo_18_1,
                cbo_19_0,cbo_19_1
            };

            foreach(ComboBox cbos in cbo)
            {
                items.Add(0, "-------");
                i = 1;
                while (i <= 24)
                {
                    cboId = i;
                    cboName = TimeSpan.FromHours(i).ToString("hh':'mm");

                    items.Add(cboId, cboName);
                    i++;
                }
                cbos.Tag = c;
                cbos.DataSource = new BindingSource(items, null);
                cbos.DisplayMember = "Value";
                cbos.ValueMember = "Key";
                cbos.SelectedIndex = 0;
                items.Clear();

                cbos.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cboSelected);

                c++;

            }

        }

        public void cboSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cb = ((ComboBox)sender);
            int i_tmp;
            int tg = Int32.Parse(cb.Tag.ToString());
            int idx;

            if(tg % 2 == 0) //if is even
            {
                i_tmp= tg - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                i_tmp = tg + 1;
            }

            //string y = cb.GetItemText(cb.SelectedItem);
            //MessageBox.Show(y.ToString());

            foreach (ComboBox cbt in panel1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()) {
                if(Int32.Parse(cbt.Tag.ToString()) == Int32.Parse(i_tmp.ToString()))
                {
                    idx = Int32.Parse(cbt.SelectedIndex.ToString());
                    cbt.SelectedIndex = idx;
                    MessageBox.Show(cbt.SelectedIndex.ToString());
                }   
            }

        }

        private void cmd_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```